# Shifting middle div to left leaves white space on its right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have three div elements inside a wrapper-div as below:

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="left-div">
        Hi
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div class="right-div">
        Bye
    </div>
</div>
```

I have applied below CSS on these which makes them appear side by side in the same row.

```
.wrapper-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 8px;
}
.right-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Now I want middle div to appear as a superscript to the text in left div. To achieve it I apply below CSS to the middle-div.

```
.middle-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: -45px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

This makes the middle-div appear as a superscript to the left-div however it leaves an undesired white space in middle-div's original position.

Could you please help me with fixing it.

Note: In my original problem I have an uncontrolled variable number of divs where I want every second div to act as a superscript to its previous div.

Comment: use negative margin instead of top/left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the wrapper to `position: relative;` and `display: flex;`
then you can simply set the middle div to `absolute` as below when you want it to do the superscript effect.

```css
.wrapper-div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.left-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.middle-div {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 2px;
}
.right-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="left-div">
        Hi
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
          Hello
        </div>
    <div class="right-div">
        Bye
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. You have been a savior @notsure. It works exactly the way I wanted it to. :)

Comment: Will try it on my complete html page now

Comment: @abhishek08aug no probs

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the div structure (put the middle inside the left), you could put the wrapper in `position:relative` and the middle div in `position:absolute` instead.
It will give :

```
.wrapper-div {
   display: inline-block;
   position:relative;
}

.middle-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 2px;
 }
```

Here is a Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePrMqv

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be more correct (and also give you less headaches) to have the "superscript" divs as subdivs like this:

```
<div class="left-div">
    Hi
    <div class="middle-div">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be both easier to read in code and easier to control with regard to positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use positioning: use negative margin.

```css
.wrapper-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-right: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <div class="left-div">
    Hi
  </div>
  <div class="middle-div">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    Bye
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen of the difference between positioning / transform / negative margin**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ)